# express.js server in the background script of a chrome extension

Tags: express, google-chrome, webpack, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to launch an express.js server within the background script of a chrome extension? I want to implement communication between instances of the chrome extension on different local browsers. My idea of doing this is to run a server on different local ports, and use web requests to communicate between them. I have tried to webpack the background.js script containing the express server, but I am having a lot of trouble getting it figured out.

Comment: Impossible. The server function cannot be webpacked.

Comment: Gotcha, do you have any ideas of how I could achieve what I am intending to?

Comment: that would require client interaction beyond just using the extension, not what we're looking for

Comment: I don't think native messaging requires interaction with the client. Well, I don't mind.